# SDL Detect High DPI/Retina Display

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm wondering what the best way to detect a high DPI display is. Currently I'm trying to use `SDL_GetDisplayDPI (int, *float, *float, *float)`, however this has only returned errors on the two different computers I tested with (MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.5 and iMac running macOS 10.12 Beta (16A238m)). For reference, my code is bellow.

```
float diagDPI = -1;
float horiDPI = -1;
float vertDPI = -1;

int dpiReturn = SDL_GetDisplayDPI (0, &diagDPI, &horiDPI, &vertDPI);
std::cout << "GetDisplayDPI() returned " << dpiReturn << std::endl;

if (dpiReturn != 0)
{

    std::cout << "Error: " << SDL_GetError () << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "DDPI: " << diagDPI << std::endl << "HDPI: " << horiDPI << std::endl << "VDPI: " << vertDPI << std::endl;
```

Unfortunately, this is only giving me something like this:

```
/* Output */
GetDisplayDPI() returned -1
Error: 
DDPI: -1
HDPI: -1
VDPI: -1
Not Retina
```

I also tried comparing the OpenGL drawable size with the SDL window size, but `SDL_GetWindowSize (SDL_Window, *int, *int)` is returning 0s, too. That code is bellow, followed by the output.

```
int gl_w;
int gl_h;

SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize (window, &gl_w, &gl_h);
std::cout << "GL_W: " << gl_w << std::endl << "GL_H: " << gl_h << std::endl;


int sdl_w;
int sdl_h;

SDL_GetWindowSize (window, &sdl_w, &sdl_h);
std::cout << "SDL_W: " << sdl_w << std::endl << "SDL_H: " << sdl_h << std::endl;

/* Output */
GL_W: 1280
GL_H: 720
SDL_W: 0
SDL_H: 0
```

It's entirely possible that I'm doing something wrong here, or making these calls in the wrong place, but I think more likely is that I'm on the wrong track entirely. There's a hint to disallow high-dpi canvases, so there's probably a simple bool somewhere, or something that I'm missing. I have certainly looked through the wiki, and checked Google, but I can't really find any help for this. Any suggestions or feedback are welcome!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your code works for me (after I added the relevant initialization code). Can you post a minimal, complete (compilable) example that reproduces the error?

Comment: Thank you for testing this, @Galik ! I'm happy to provide a link to my project, however I'm using a 3rd party GUI toolkit, so it may be a little confusing. It should build and run without issue, though, so long as you have SDL2, SDL2_Image, and SDL2_TTF installed. The project may be found here: https://github.com/2CatStudios/LightYear/tree/retina-support/Project/Universal/LightYear The relevant code is in RenderingManager.cpp at line 14 https://github.com/2CatStudios/LightYear/blob/retina-support/Project/Universal/LightYear/src/RenderingManager.cpp

Comment: @Galik What OS are you using? I suppose it is possible that this is an issue with the Cocoa implementation of the `SDL_GetDisplayDPI` function.

Comment: Do you ever call the library initialization function: `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);`?

Comment: In kiss_draw.c ( https://github.com/2CatStudios/LightYear/blob/retina-support/Project/Universal/LightYear/lib/kiss_sdl-1.0.12/kiss_draw.c ) , at line 200 `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);` is called.

Comment: I'm using `Linux`. All I can think of is make sure the library initialization function is called before the code in question.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that I did test the above code in a pure SDL example project from Will Usher ( http://www.willusher.io/pages/sdl2/ ), and I saw the same error.

Comment: @Galik I just moved the code elsewhere (later), but the results are the same. Thank you for taking a look at this, though, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a .framework installation of SDL when I encountered this issue. For an unrelated reason, I trashed the .framework SDL files (image and ttf as well), and built SDL from source (thus transitioning to a "unix-style" SDL-installation). To my surprise, `SDL_GetDisplayDPI ()` is now returning 0, setting the values of DDPI, HDPI, and VDPI, to 109 on a non-retina iMac, and 113.5 on a retina MacBook Pro. I'm not certain that these are correct/accurate, but it is consistent between launches, so I'll work with it.

At this point, I'm not sure if it was a bug, which has been fixed in the repo, or was an issue with my .framework files. On a somewhat unrelated note, `SDL_GetBasePath ()` and `SDL_GetPrefPath ()`, which also weren't working, now return the expected values. If you're also experiencing any of these problems on macOS, try compiling and installing SDL from source (https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL).

Thanks for your input, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm not answering your question directly, and want to reiterate one thing you tried.

On a Macbook pro, when an SDL window is on an external display, `SDL_GetWindowSize` and `SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize` return the same values. If the window is on a Retina screen, they're different. Specifically, the drawable size is 2x larger in each dimension.